# About ATmega32 event system

Tags: avr, events

From my reading on internet i found that the Event system allows peripherals to trigger each other without involving the CPU...does the event system is software or hardware?also does ATmega32 support it? also can any one give me a real application for event system?

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @NickGammon https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/8-bit/peripherals/core-independent/event-system

Comment: The Atmega32 is not listed in the device list for the event system, that is on that site

Comment: @chrisl could you give me some example for event system?

Comment: Which Arduino are you using? This question might be better put to the [AVR Freaks](https://www.avrfreaks.net/) web site as it doesn't seem to directly involve any Arduino as such.

Comment: @NickGammon I don't use arduino..I use Atmega32

Answer (score 2):

The 'old' ATmega 8 bit microcontrollers don't have an event system peripheral. The new "megaAVR 0 series" has an event system. Atmega 4809 on Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2 and on Nano Every is "megaAVR 0-series". The event system of the new ATmegas is similar to SAMD event system I know.

ARM MCUs for example SAMD by Atmel/Microchip used in Arduino Zero and MKR have an event system. Event system is a MCU peripheral. It enables direct communication between peripherals without the involvement of the CPU of the MCU.

The MCU peripherals are what makes the MCU a MCU. Examples of peripherals are GPIO pins, external interrupts, timers, SERCOM, watchdog...

To give you an example of use of the event system. To perform AC phase cutting with a Triac the Triac must be pulsed at right time after zero crossing. (It turns off self at next zero crossing.) To achieve this with MCU, the MCU must sense the input from the zero crossing detection circuit, then start timing the requested off time, then start a pulse to triac's gate and then stop the pulse.

It can be implemented with an external interrupt function for zero crossing, which starts a timer to generate a pulse on a wave output pin.

On ARM MCU it is possible to setup the event system to start the timer on external interrupt over an event, without an interrupt function. Then the CPU of the MCU is not involved in phase cutting after the initial configuration of the peripherals.

After setting up the zero crossing detector input pin for external interrupt without interrupt function and setting up the timer to execute one-shot pulse, the event system will re-trigger the timer on external interrupt.

a simple Arduino SAMD lib for a Triac/ZC module (in development):

```
#ifndef _TRIAC_LIB_
#define _TRIAC_LIB_

namespace Triac {

const unsigned long AC_WAVE_MICROS = 10000; // at 50 Hz
const int TIMER_PRESCALER = 8;
const unsigned long PULSE_PERIOD = ((F_CPU / 1000000) * 200) / TIMER_PRESCALER;

Tcc* TCC;

void syncTCC() {
  while (TCC->SYNCBUSY.reg & TCC_SYNCBUSY_MASK);
}

void zeroCrossing() {
}


void setup(byte zcPin, byte triacPin) {

  // setup the external interrupt
  attachInterrupt(zcPin, zeroCrossing, RISING);
  uint8_t ulExtInt = g_APinDescription[zcPin].ulExtInt;
  EIC->EVCTRL.reg |= (1 << ulExtInt);// enable event
  EIC->INTENCLR.reg = EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT(1 << ulExtInt); // turn-off interrupt

  const PinDescription& pinDesc = g_APinDescription[triacPin]; // Arduino pin description
  TCC = (Tcc*) GetTC(pinDesc.ulPWMChannel);
  uint8_t tcChannel = GetTCChannelNumber(pinDesc.ulPWMChannel);

  // setup the pin as TCC wave out pin
  PORT->Group[pinDesc.ulPort].PINCFG[pinDesc.ulPin].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
  PORT->Group[pinDesc.ulPort].PMUX[pinDesc.ulPin >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_F;

  // setup the timer

  REG_GCLK_CLKCTRL = (uint16_t) (GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN | GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0 | GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(GCM_TCC0_TCC1)); // assign clock
  while ( GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY == 1 );

  TCC->CTRLA.bit.SWRST = 1; // reset timer
  syncTCC();
  TCC->WAVE.reg |= TCC_WAVE_WAVEGEN_NPWM; // normal PWM as wave output mode
  syncTCC();
  TCC->CTRLBSET.reg = TCC_CTRLBSET_ONESHOT | TCC_CTRLBSET_DIR; //one shot and count down
  syncTCC();

  TCC->PER.reg = ((F_CPU / 1000000) * AC_WAVE_MICROS) / TIMER_PRESCALER; // initial value of period (triac off)
  syncTCC();
  TCC->CC[tcChannel].reg = PULSE_PERIOD; // pin on at compare match and off at 0 (timer counts down)
  syncTCC();

  TCC->EVCTRL.reg |= TCC_EVCTRL_TCEI0 | TCC_EVCTRL_EVACT0_RETRIGGER; // retrigger on event
  syncTCC();
  TCC->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV8 | TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE; // set prescaler and enable
  syncTCC();

  // event system
  PM->APBCMASK.reg |= PM_APBCMASK_EVSYS; // power it on
  GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(EVSYS_GCLK_ID_0) | GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN | GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN(0); // assign a clock
  while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);

  EVSYS->CTRL.bit.SWRST = 1; // reset
  while(EVSYS->CTRL.bit.SWRST);

  EVSYS->USER.reg = EVSYS_ID_USER_TCC0_EV_0 | EVSYS_USER_CHANNEL(1); // set user TCC0 event 0 on channel 0
  EVSYS->CHANNEL.reg = EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHANNEL(0) | EVSYS_CHANNEL_PATH_ASYNCHRONOUS | // channel 0 is async
      EVSYS_CHANNEL_EDGSEL_FALLING_EDGE | EVSYS_CHANNEL_EVGEN(EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_0 + ulExtInt); // source is ext.interrupt
  while (!EVSYS->CHSTATUS.bit.USRRDY0);
}

/*
 * r is from interval <0.0, 1.0>
 */
void setPeriod(float r) {
  unsigned long period = ((F_CPU / 1000000) * ((1.0 - r) * AC_WAVE_MICROS)) / TIMER_PRESCALER;
  TCC->PER.reg = period + PULSE_PERIOD;
  syncTCC();
}

}
#endif
```

[other SAMD example](https://martinvb.com/wp/as5030-magnetic-encoder-capturing-a-pwm-signal-with-an-atsamd21/)

Comment: Thank you sir...your answer is very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The ATmega32 has a coupe of peripheral-to-peripheral communication
features that are in some way similar to the Event System:

- You can use the analog comparator to trigger an input capture on
  Timer 1.
- You can use the analog comparator, external interrupt 0, Timer 0, or
  Timer 1 to trigger a conversion on the ADC.

These are the only ones I know about. As you can see, it's a very
limited functionality. From what I read, the Event System looks like a
generalization of this idea. You have many peripherals that can trigger
events (event emitters), many that can be triggered by such events
(event receivers), and you can connect any event emitter to any event
receiver. You thus have much more flexibility than the very limited
peripheral-to-peripheral communication facilities provided by the
ATmega32.

The configuration of the event system (emitter to receiver connections)
is performed by your software. However, once the connection is
established, the peripheral-to-peripheral communication is entirely
hardware, and does not depend on the CPU.

Comment: Thank you sir....I am very thankful...